# Doing hex in python to a full byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

Is there a way to get python to print an even number of bytes when formatting hex? For example:

```
>>> hex(12)
'0xc'
>>> f'{12:#x}'
'0xc'
>>> f'{12:#X}'
'0XC'
>>> f'{12:X}'
'C'
>>> f'{12:x}'
'c'
```

Additionally, does python have a formatted that will separate bytes when there are multiple? For example:

```
>>> hex(1000)
'0x3e8' # 0e e8
```

Or would I need to create my own formatter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format fixed length hex values in a string using a format specifier...

- 0 - padded with 0's
- 4 - number of digits
- x - hex value

like this:

```
 '{:04x}'.format(12)
```

Which returns:

```
'000c'
```

AFAIK you'll need to have a custom format function to group by position.  Maybe something like this:

```
hex_value = '0123456789abcdef'
' '.join(hex_value[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(hex_value), 2))
```

Which will return:

```
'01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef'
```